# How do I put an ArrayList<Integer> in a String Variable?

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to put an ArrayList and some letters into a String variable in order to display it in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog yet I dont really know how to do that.

```
String output = "";
for(int i = 0; i<=l; i++){
   if (i <= 10){
      output += i+1 + ".: "+ highscorelist.get(i)+"%\n";
   }
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These are the top score:\n"+output);
```

My String should be "output", l is the amount of Arrayfields I put in the highscorelist.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is really not clear.

Comment: You're on the right way I guess, but what problem are you facing?

Comment: Any particular error you are getting ?
Code looking good to produce desired result.

Comment: Agreed. The code looks to work just fine: https://ideone.com/TrZaNP

Comment: When I try to display it, it seem slike that output is like empty, so i end up having that Messagebox with  "These are the top score:" and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be working, but you have there one mistake. In for and if you have <=, this will loop l + 1 times and it will put 11 records into output variable. Replace it with <.

```
for(int i = 0; i<l; i++){
    if (i < 10){
    output += i+1 + ".: "+ highscorelist.get(i)+"%\n";
    }
}
```